# Need to remove all non letter elements from a string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

with writing this assembly code i cant get this option to work with the removing a non character letter. it will either iterate through the string with all the comparisons and then display the same string with no non characters removed.
I'm trying to get the letter characters into a tempString that i can then move to edx to be displayed.

it takes in a string and removes all non letter characters
then displays the new string using another procedure that uses writestring and register edx

```
;// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
option3 PROC
;// Description: removes all non-letter elements. There is no requirement for
;// option2 to have been executed.
;// Receives: ecx - length of string
;// edx - offset of string
;// ebx - offset of string length variable
;// esi preserved
;// Returns: nothing, but the string will have all non-letter elements removed

.data


.code

push esi
call option5

L3:
mov al, byte ptr [edx+esi]

cmp al, 41h
jb notletter
cmp al, 5Ah
ja notletter
cmp al, 61h
jb notletter
cmp al,7Ah
ja notletter


mov byte ptr [edx+esi], al

notletter:
inc esi
loop L3


pop esi
call option5
call waitmsg

option3 ENDP
```

Comment: _"I need help"_ is much too vague. What _specifically_ are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

First, think of this as copying from one place to the same place; where bytes that need to be ignored are not copied. You need 2 registers for this - one to keep track of where to get the next byte (e.g. maybe `esi`), and one to keep track of where to store the next byte/letter (e.g. maybe `edi`).

Second, your "is it a letter" branches aren't right (e.g. the letter 'A' or the value 0x41 will be less than the letter 'a' or the value 0x61). It needs to be more like:

```
    cmp al,'A'       ;Is the value too low to be any letter?
    jb .notLetter    ; yes
    cmp al,'z'       ;Is the value too high to be any letter?
    ja .notLetter    ; yes
    cmp al,'Z'       ;Is the value low enough to be a capital letter?
    jbe .isLetter    ; yes
    cmp al,'a'       ;Is the value high enough to be a lower case letter?
    jae .isLetter    ; yes
                     ; no, not a letter
.notLetter:
```

For example (NASM):

```
;Inputs:
; ecx    Length of original string
; esi    Address of original string
;
;Outputs
; edi    Length of new string
; ebx    Address of new string

filterString:
    mov edi,esi      ;edi = address to store string (same address as original string)
    mov ebx,esi      ;ebx = address of both strings (used later)
    jecxz .done      ;Do nothing if the original string has zero length
    cld

.nextByte:
    lodsb            ;AL = next byte, ESI incremented
    cmp al,'A'       ;Is the value too low to be any letter?
    jb .doneByte     ; yes, not a letter
    cmp al,'z'       ;Is the value too high to be any letter?
    ja .doneByte     ; yes, not a letter
    cmp al,'Z'       ;Is the value low enough to be a capital letter?
    jbe .isLetter    ; yes, it's a capital letter
    cmp al,'a'       ;Is the value high enough to be a lower case letter?
    jb .doneByte     ; no, not a letter
                     ; yes, it's a lower case letter
.isLetter:
    stosb            ;Store AL at EDI, and increment EDI

.doneByte:
    loop .nextByte
.done:
    sub edi,ebx      ;edi = length of new string
    ret
```

Comment: You can of course optimize the check for alphabetic into `or al, 0x20` / `sub al, 'a'` / `cmp al,'z'-'a' / ja .non_letter`.  (Or do that to a copy of AL because this is destructive.)  [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54585515)    (Hmm, I think we can adjust that to use `lea edx, [eax - 'A']` and AND, instead of a separate `mov`, unless that introduces false positives.)