# How to remove a char from a 4-byte string in MIPS32 assembly using a shift?

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm new to MIPS32 assembly and trying to delete a character in a string (delete the first character, specifically) stored in the .data section but have no clue how to do so.

In the following line of code, is there a way to make it so that test just equals "bc" instead of "abc"

```
test:           .asciiz     "abc"
```

Is this simply a matter of using something like logical shifting left by 2 to remove the first char, or do I need to offset by something, or is there an opcode to just straight delete it?

Comment: Maybe you can look at this [removing-spaces-from-string-in-mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527125/removing-spaces-from-string-in-mips)

Answer (score 0):

As [Need to remove all non letter elements from a string in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630695/need-to-remove-all-non-letter-elements-from-a-string-in-assembly) (for x86) explains, removing a character in a string means copying over the whole rest of the string.

In your case it's just 3 bytes left out of the 4 (including the terminating `0`).  So yes, you could do this just by shifting the word by 8 bits (1 byte).  Especially if you make sure `test` is word-aligned with `.p2align 2` before it, so you can safely `lw` and `sw` all 4 bytes with one load.

For little-endian MIPS (like MARS simulates), that would be a right shift because the first byte in memory is the least significant.  And right shifts shift out the low (least significant) bits.

For big-endian MIPS (most significant byte first, like some real MIPS CPUs operate), that would be a left shift, removing the most significant byte and shifting the low bits up.

---

Note that this will leave the word at `test` being `'b', 'c', 0, 0`.  So yes, as an implicit-length string it's `"bc"`.

Also note that if you just had a pointer in a register, you could get a pointer to `"bc"` by simply incrementing it by 1 instead of modifying memory.  Like `addiu $t0, $t0, 1`.

Or equivalently, `la $t0, test+1` is a pointer to 1 byte past the start.