# MIPS problem. How to get rid of certain characters

Tags: assembly, mips

My problem is that I have the string "abcABCGROUND?!?#" and I have to remove all the characters that are not numbers in that string. So the result must be an empty string. I have developed some code for it. And what I want to do is to say that if the character that im checking is lower than '0' then it is not a number and I remove it. And the same thing happens if the character is greater then '9'. It is not a number so I remove it. The problem comes when I try to remove the character. What should I do? I have tried making a move $a0,$t0 to have the character on a temporary register and the I add $a0,a0,1 to skip to the next character and continue checking the next one. But I cant remove it that way.
Thank you for your help :)

```
input:      .space 80
test1:      .asciiz "abcABCGROUND?!?#"

        .text

main:       la $a0, test1
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        li $v0, 10
        syscall

leave0_9:   lbu $t2, ($a0)
        blt $t2, '0', end
        bgt $t2, '9', end
        move $t2,$t3
        lb $a0,($0)
end:        
        add $a0, $a0, 1
```

Comment: I would recommend solving the problem algorithmically first, for example by writing a C version, then translating that working solution into assembly.  This way you can focus separately on algorithms vs. details of assembly.  (To those who might complain that this is too much work, the C version should be about 2-4 lines code.)

Comment: basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527125/removing-spaces-from-string-in-mips although that doesn't have any great answers.  As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630695/need-to-remove-all-non-letter-elements-from-a-string-in-assembly (for x86) explains, removing one or more characters in a string means copying over the characters being kept, to lower addresses.  You can do that in-place or to a separate destination array.